# How to put a non-breaking space in \cite

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, line-breaking

How do I put a non-breaking space inside a `\cite` macro with several citations? `\cite{ref1,~ref2}` causes an error. If I leave the space out, one is inserted and this is causing the citation to span two lines. I am using bibstyle `plain`.

Comment: Why do you want an unbreakable space after a comma? A comma at the end of a line is a perfect position for a line break!

Comment: I am using bibstyle `plain` and I end up with [1, 2,\n 3, 4] which looks bad.

Comment: @jaybee: well, when you have 4 references in one bracket (which is generally correct), I suggest to leave it as is, i.e. `[1, 2,\n 3, 4]`, because the bracket is long and the lines would be too empty/full. The only other possibility is to re-phrase the text slightly, but this should be done in the final version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it is an isolated thing (i.e. you need to do it once in your document), put `\hbox{\cite{ref1, ref2}}`

Answer (score 3):

have you tried the option `[space]` with the package `cite` ?

Comment: This is more of a question/comment than an answer.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt On the other hand, it is somehow an answer (and probably a correct answer), just written down with a question mark in the end...

Comment: @tohecz: It's rude to answer a question with a question. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't use any packages that modify `\cite` & friends, a general solution is to change the definition of `\@citex`, namely, to replace the breakable space (accompanied by a penalty of 1000) with a non-breakable space. (Note: For convenience, I'm using the [etoolbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to do so.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@citex}{%
  ,\penalty\@m\ %
}{%
  ,~%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

XXXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXX XXiiiiiii \cite{x,y}.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{x} A bibitem.

\bibitem{y} Another bibitem.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```